# why does my motion detector turns on during startup

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, security, alarm

i am trying to use a motion detector to turn on a light and small alarm using a smart switch to power it so i can program and use phone to operate problem is when it switches on at night it starts by turning on therefore setting off alarm before going into sensor mode ( alarm going off every time it starts )looking for sensor that wont be in the on position during startup have tried several with same results

[

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: We'll need a lot more information in order to answer this question. As it is, there's no way we can help you without knowing what you're working with, how you're setting it up, and so on.

Comment: Are you cutting power to the motion sensor?  Why? Can you have the motion sensor powered 24x7?

Comment: Please format the wall of words into a few proper sentences.

Comment: Maybe a calibration phase at startup?

Answer (score 2):

If this is an outdoor motion detector that has a light sensitive switch, it would normally not turn on every time the sun sets, before going into sensor mode. It will have an initial turn on when it is powered up, but not when it just becomes dark. So replacing the motion detector with a different model may be all you need to do.

However, if you have the motion detector switched by a timer, a manual switch or something else, then yes, you are stuck with the initial "on" at power up.

The way around this problem is to place the timer or manual switch *after* the motion detector. Keep the detector powered at all times, and place the switch in the circuit after the detector, where usually the lights are wired. Then you can enable/disable the alarm by applying the switch and there will be no initial start-up alarm.

Answer (score 2):

### You must keep power on the motion sensor 24x7.

What you actually have there is a consumer lamp appliance including a motion sensor *and* ambient light sensor.   You can't cut power to that, or it will malfunction.

First, cutting and restoring power places the unit into "initial setup".  The first thing it does is turn on the light, to tell the installer that "yes, you have hooked up power correctly and I am energized".  That's a mandatory and normal part of setup.

Second, cutting power may wipe its memory first of sensor calibration, but also of day/night light levels ***in this location***.  It needs 24 hours turned-on to learn those accurately; otherwise it's relying on factory defaults.

*So stop cutting power to it*.

### Use *components* built to purpose.

I don't know why you'd connect an alarm to the light turning on, but it sounds like you are trying to custom-rig something "Rube Goldberg" style, and you are using sophisticated consumer products that are not made for that, and are not cooperating.

Instead, you should use electronic components specifically made to do *that one thing*.  For instance, 12-volt motion sensors are [inexpensive commodity items](https://www.wiredco.com/12VDC-8-Amp-IR-Infrared-Motion-Sensor-Control-p/ledinfrared1.htm) that are all over Amazon. (most are Chinesium but I'm not too worried when they're only 12 volts).

When doing custom control stuff like that, you're really better off working in 12 volts, where you have a range of tech available to you, including Arduino and Raspberry Pi (with WiFi and cellular data modules, even). There's really no limit to what you can build, and it will *do what you ask it to*, unlike trying to mash consumer products together that were never intended for that.